# Copy from LibreOffice to CKEditor

Tags: libreoffice, paste

If I copy a LibreOffice Table (spreadsheet, not writer) to CKEDitor4 it does copy and past an image.

With CKEditor5 the table gets copied.

Is there a way to get this working with CKEditor4?

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/demo/

Version:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- LibreOffice 6.0.7.3
- Firefox 64.0

Comment: This seems like a CKEditor4 support question (or bug). CKEditor4 is not distributed by Ubuntu and has their own support community and bug tracker.

Comment: @user535733 yes, you are right. But maybe there is something which I (the ubuntu user) can do, to walk around this problem.

Comment: did you try to export the table in to html and perform the copy from the generated webpage?

Comment: @AtomiX84 no, I did not try this.

Comment: Try, may the CKEditor4 will more happy to receive a paste from a know format.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue. I open calc, fill in some cells, copy them and paste into your 5/demo (link above). It pastes a table, not an image

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz did you read the question? CKEditor5 works, this question is about why it does not work in CKEditor4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test out this, if you just copy in to CKEditor4 directly from libreoffice calc the result is:

[image]

Instead if you initilizate a table before in the editor and past from calc in to it result is:

[image]

which is formatted a bit better. But in both case it is past it as a text.
I do this operation with libreoffice:

- Version: 6.1.4.2
- Build ID: 1:6.1.4-3
- Browser: Chromium 72.0.3626.7

OS: Debian codename=Buster (actual testing branch)

**Update**
As per the comment the "issue" was caused by the Firefox web browse, apparently it is unable to past from Libreoffice as text, with chromium (and we can suppose also chrome) it works!

Comment: You get a real table, not an image which looks like a table?

Comment: yes, maybe the Libreoffice version?

Comment: oh, maybe useful information, I use chromium as web browser.

Comment: you are right. It was the browser. It works with chromium, but not with firefox. Up to now I was lazy and sticked to firefox which I use since ages. Maybe it is time to change. (I use Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: hehehe, lazy is the worst beast for all of us! I'll update the answer with the information that was browser firefox not interact well with CKEditor.

Comment: “I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it.”

― Bill Gates

Comment: never words were more true